# PowerShell - Writing to file and close it

Tags: powershell

I am using those functions to write to the log but I noticed that sometimes the log is still opened after the script finished and when the script run for the second time I get an exception that the file is already in use. I don't know how it could be possible because every time a new log is created so no overlapping should be here, how can I close the log after the script finished?
Maybe I need to add protection in the function? I noticed that when its happens a new log was created. maybe the writing is too fast?
How can I add a retry for the line that not written? maybe inside a catch?

WARNING: Exception calling "AppendAllText" with "2" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This function is creating the log:

```
function Createlog {

    if ($CreateLog -ne "no") {
        try {
            $subfolder = "PatchVerificationLogs"
            $Logs = "$FilesPath\$subfolder"
            if (!(Test-Path -Path $Logs)) {
                New-Item -Path $Logs -ItemType "directory" 1>$null
            }
        }
        catch {}
        $Stamp = get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss
        $hostname = $env:computername
        $UserName = $env:USERNAME
        $logName = $hostname + '-' + $Stamp + ".log"
        $loglocation = $Logs + "\" + $logName

    }
```

This function to write into the log:

```
Function Write-Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [ValidateSet("INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL", "DEBUG")]
        [String]
        $Level = "INFO",

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [string]
        $Message,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string]
        $logfile
    )
    $stampp = get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss

    $Line = "$Stampp $Level $Message`r`n"
    If ($logfile -ne "") {
        #Add-Content $loglocation -Value $Line -Force
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logfile, $Line)
    }
    #Else {
    #    Write-Output $Line
    #}
}
```

This is how I am writing to the log:

```
Write-Log -logfile $loglocation -Message ""
```

Comment: I would have function `Createlog` output the full path to the log so you can capture it in the main script. Then in `Write-Log` use `Test-Path` instead of `$logfile -ne ""`

Comment: This is not my problem.. I have $logfile for all the Write-Log. actually I can add it to the function as constant and only write: Write-Log -Message ""

Comment: What about try catch for [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logfile, $Line)
and continue in the catch?

Comment: This is the way to do it?
try { 
      [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logfile, $Line)
      }
    catch { $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" }

Or 
ErrorAction Continue

Comment: What I meant was that your CreateLog function only creates a local variable `$loglocation` since you didn't scope it with `$script:loglocation`. It only exists within that function, so there is no telling what you are sending through to the second function.

Comment: @Theo I have it but didn't mentioned it in the question 
Set-Variable -Name "loglocation" -Value $loglocation -Scope global. otherwise it was failed at the first writing

Comment: I added a retry/ hope its ok
$tries = 0
    If ($logfile -ne "") {
        try {
            [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logfile, $Line)
            }
        catch {
           $tries = 0
        while ($tries -lt 3) {
            try {
                [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($logfile, $Line)
                $tries = 10
            }
            catch {
                $tries = $tries + 1
                Write-Host "Unable to write to log , retry number: [$tries]"
                }
            }        
        }
    }

Comment: Why not simply using the native PowerShell command [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content)?

Comment: @iRon with Add-Content there are many issues, i tried it first therefore I changed to AppendAllText more robust

Comment: "*`Add-Content` there are many issues*" What issues? The only thing that shows from your question is that `AppendAllText` isn't robust... [Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations)

Comment: You're not showing the code that creates the log file, which is probably where the problem lies.